# Cylinder Figures on Canvas SWT Draw2D

Tags: java, user-interface, canvas, swt, draw2d

I understand that Draw2D doesn't provide support for more complex figures like cylinders and that we have to "construct them ourselves". I couldn't find much support for that route online. Is there any way I can construct a custom Figure representing a cylinder. I hope this isn't too broad but could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you add an image of how that figure should look like?

Comment: [Here](http://doublexia.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/use-eclipse-draw2d-to-create-custom-figure/) someone creates a Hexagon. Maybe that's something to look at.

Comment: @Baz How do you arrive at vertices when only given the enclosing Rectangle's dimensions?

Comment: Sorry, but I've no idea what you're talking about :/

Comment: @Baz The example you pointed out follows the method of first identifying the vertices of the figure to be created, based on the enclosing Rectangle rect. My question is how can we follow the same methodology i.e,  identify all the vertices of the cylinder within rect?

Comment: No idea, sorry. I just found it, but I'm not entirely sure you can use it. That's why I didn't post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to constructing your own cylinder figure geometrically, you can use the `GeoShapeCylinderFigure` class from the `org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.geoshapes.internal.draw2d.figures` package.